# clear or reset options of dropdown after refresh in JQuery/Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

How can  I clear the options of select box after refresh ...  I have two select boxes and both of their values after refresh didn't clear or reset
i am working in code igniter
here is my code.

```
    <?php echo form_dropdown('cat_id', $records2, '#', 'class="cho" id="category"');?>


 <script type="text/javascript">// 
 $(document).ready(function(){       
    $('#category').change(function(){        
        $("#items > option").remove(); //it is not working
        var category_id = $('#category').val();  
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "testController/get_items/"+category_id,

            success: function(items)
            {
                $.each(items,function(item_id,item_name) 
                {
                    var opt = $('<option />'); 
                    opt.val(item_id);
                    opt.text(item_name);
                    $('#items').append(opt); 
                });
            }

        });

    });
});
// ]]>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
$("#items > option").remove(); //it is not working
```

try this

```
$("#items).html("");
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/HUzzV/) is simple jsFiddle for you

**UPDATE:**

You might also consider to build you options markup first and then replace it at once, rather then sequentially append items.

```js
$("#category").change(function(){        
    var category_id = $("#category").val();  
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "testController/get_items/" + category_id,
        success: function(items)
        {
            var options = "";
            $.each(items, function(item_id, item_name) 
            {
                options += "<option value=\"" + item_id + "\">" + item_name + "</option>";
            });
            $("#items").html(options);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: where i write this line ? after the ready function or change function ?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 $("#items").empty();
```

`empty()` method will clear all html

API Reference http://api.jquery.com/empty

Comment: where do i adjust this or write this line in my code because if i write just after the ready function it will get empty but then after selecting the option of 1st select box it is doing nothing and if i write after the change function it is not working then

Comment: in your change handler code..  not sure why `$("#items > option").remove();` doesn't work...and `empty()` is to replace it. Are their `optgroup` tags? If so removing the `>` would make your `remove` work

Comment: nope they are note ..i am working in code igniter and i am using this    <?php echo form_dropdown('cat_id', $records2, '#', 'class="cho" id="category"');?>

Comment: define `refresh`... is this is a page reload problem? If it is can clear selected values using `$("#items").val('')`. Not sure why would need to do it thoug, can clear selectd in php

Comment: refresh means when i reload the page

Comment: OK... am confused ... since you provided AJAX code, and change handler, now not sure what eleemnt you are trying to change or what issue really is. Also why isn't php sending proper form setup?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#items')
    .find('option')
    .remove()
    .end();
```

IE6

```
$('#items')
    .empty();
```

Comment: tell me the position where do i write this line?

Comment: first line within the change event anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the document.ready event handler. Everything is contained within
 $('#category').change(function(){ meaning nothing will happen on page refresh.

Comment: then what should i do ? you mean all the values remain static there?

Comment: I am busy at the moment. If you don't get an answer I will hopefully give you one later tonight.